# Vim autocompletion for Java

Tags: java, unix, vim, plugins, autocomplete

What are the available plugins for vim to emulate NetBeans autocompletion? I'm developing in a pure command line environment. For C vim was great, but the lack of automatic import and class property autocompletion in vim is a fatal productivity killer when working with enterprise-level Java applications. In the other hand, IDE with vim plugin isn't an option, as I'm working through SSH without X-server.

Comment: Mount your partition with ssh and use a local program to edit remote files. You could also install X and invoke ssh -X servername netbean. You could also mock whatever services or device localy or simply recreate the environment locally instead of coding directly on the remote machine. If you still want a better vim-java ide have a look at Eclim. http://eclim.org/index.html

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [this](https://github.com/artur-shaik/vim-javacomplete2). Easy to install and use. Copy the plugin to your server's ~/.vim/plugin directory.

Comment: Error detected while processing function javacomplete#Start..javacomplete#server#Start:
line   26:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/***/.vim/bundle/vim-javacomplete2/autoload/javavibridge.py", line 28, in <module>
    class JavaviBridge():
  File "/**/.vim/bundle/vim-javacomplete2/autoload/javavibridge.py", line 30, in JavaviBridge
    pythonVersion = sys.version_info.major
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'major'
line   29:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'JavaviBridge'

Comment: Make sure that you have the versions of vim, java and javac required by the plugin. if all are fine try adding the following to your .vimrc
"autocmd Filetype java setlocal omnifunc=javacomplete#Complete"

Comment: I also have issues.  It's not clear how to install it without a vundle, pathogen etc. I have the right versions.

Comment: This did not work for me. I get a lot of errors when trying to open a file in vim.